# Twitter Typeahead with Local Dataset

Tags: twitter, dataset, local, typeahead

I can't understand why this tutorial example does not work for me:

I have external js libraries:

"https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"
"http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/releases/latest/typeahead.bundle.js"

And this code on load document:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input.typeahead').typeahead({
        name: 'cars',
        local: ['Audi', 'BMW', 'Bugatti', 'Ferrari', 'Ford', 'Lamborghini', 'Mercedes Benz', 'Porsche', 'Rolls-Royce', 'Volkswagen']
    });
});
</script>
```

I have css:

```
   <style type="text/css">
        .bs-example {
            font-family: sans-serif;
            position: relative;
            margin: 100px;
        }
        .typeahead, .tt-query, .tt-hint {
            border: 2px solid #CCCCCC;
            border-radius: 8px;
            font-size: 24px;
            height: 30px;
            line-height: 30px;
            outline: medium none;
            padding: 8px 12px;
            width: 396px;
        }
        .typeahead {
            background-color: #FFFFFF;
        }
        .typeahead:focus {
            border: 2px solid #0097CF;
        }
        .tt-query {
            box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075) inset;
        }

        .tt-hint {
            color: #999999;
        }

        .tt-dropdown-menu {
            background-color: #FFFFFF;
            border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
            border-radius: 8px;
            box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
            margin-top: 12px;
            padding: 8px 0;
            width: 422px;
        }

        .tt-suggestion {
            font-size: 24px;
            line-height: 24px;
            padding: 3px 20px;
        }

            .tt-suggestion.tt-is-under-cursor {
                background-color: #0097CF;
                color: #FFFFFF;
            }

            .tt-suggestion p {
                margin: 0;
            }
    </style>
```

And html code:

```
<body>
    <div class="bs-example">
        <input type="text" class="typeahead tt-query" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false">
    </div>
</body>
```

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: What error/problem you are facing ?

Comment: typeahead plugin does not work at all ! Drop down menu not shown, hint string not shown etc.

Comment: IMO the above piece of code works only on typeahead < 0.9.3. If you are using the latest typeahead you should either use bloodhound or you should use the first example from here http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/

Comment: Thanks! Yes the reason is new typeahead works differnetly from earlier version.